# how to check for multiple groups of values exists in same table from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e443688/2

If I have a list of values:

1. a@test.com
2. b@test.com
3. c@test.com

And my table has a column called `email` I can run a query like

`select email from datatable where email in ('a@test.com', 'b@test.com', 'c@test.com')`

to find whether they exist.

However, if my list of values consists of at least 2 columns:

1. a@test.com, manager
2. b@test.com, editor
3. c@test.com, editor

And my table has two columns `email` and `job_title`, how do I run a query to check if there are rows that match the values I am searching for?

I don't want to know how many there are. I do want to know which value group exists.

Ideally if my query can return back something like this

```
email | job_title | exists
------|-----------|-------
a@test.com | manager | 1
b@test.com | editor | 0
c@test.com | editor | 1
```

Or just

```
email | job_title 
------|-----------
a@test.com | manager 
c@test.com | editor
```

That's good enough

Comment: `where concat(email, '-', job_title) in ('a@test.com-manager', 'b@test.com-editor, 'c@test.com-editor')`

Comment: Hi @Kim, are you going to hard code the values or you are going to do it dynamically?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @marekful comment and concatenate the two values.

Also @Strawberry's suggestion works as well.

Here's the fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e443688/3

And the query was

`select id from emails where (email,job_title) in(('a@test.com','manager'),('b@test.com','editor'),('c@test.com','editor'))`

Answer (score 0):

What 'marekful' suggested is a pretty good option. If you are looking for an alternative way, here's another option:

```
select email 
from datatable
where (email = 'a@test.com' and job_title = 'manager')
or (email = 'b@test.com' and job_title = 'editor')
or (email = 'c@test.com' and job_title = 'editor');
```

Comment: Or (x,y) in(('a','b'),('a','c'),('d','e')) - although capacity to use indexes is , i think, diminished